# Can't extract href link from html_node in rvest

Tags: html, r, web-scraping, xpath, rvest

When I use the rvest package xpath and and try to get the embedded links (football team names) from the sites I get an empty result. Could someone help this?

The code is as follows:

```
library(rvest)
 
url <- read_html('https://www.transfermarkt.com/premier-league/startseite/wettbewerb/GB1') 
    
xpath <- as.character('/html/body/div[2]/div[11]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div')

url %>%
  html_node(xpath=xpath) %>% 
  html_attr('href')
```

Comment: Which links are you trying to extract?

Comment: @RonakShah I am trying to extract the football team links in the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get all the links using :

```
library(rvest)

url <- 'https://www.transfermarkt.com/premier-league/startseite/wettbewerb/GB1'


url %>%
  read_html %>%
  html_nodes('td.hauptlink a') %>%
  html_attr('href') %>%
  .[. != '#'] %>%
  paste0('https://www.transfermarkt.com', .) %>%
  unique() %>%
  head(20)
```

Comment: This is great! It works, thank you. How did you get the css selector from?

Comment: Right clicked on the page and did inspect element to find the relevant portion to be extracted.

Comment: Thats great. So do you just add the 'a' in there as I can't see that in the source code.

Comment: `a` is used to select the anchor tag which comes after `td.hauptlink`.

Comment: There is 20 teams in the table and  70 links - I think the css has picked up more links than necessary. How would one go around this if not using gadgetselector?

Comment: It had lot of duplicate links and links from other tables. I updated the answer to include only the unique links and the first 20 ones.

Comment: I would like to run a function on this list that I could extract the player links within those teams, so this means that the player links will be different lengths. So the head(20) if am using the above as a function. So how would I go around that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229758/discussion-between-mohamed-yusuf-and-ronak-shah).